# Link to bxSlider Slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

### Problem:

I'm using bxSlider as main content on main page. I have `bxSlider` with 12 img for each slide. Then i have 12 blocks of html code for each slide. With jQuery i'm changing the content together with `bxSlider` using `onSlidePrev` and `onSlideNext` callbacks. Every thing works fine but the problem is when i click on links to the slides. I have a main menu with goes to selected slide, also have the "pager" and when i click on this things the content is not changing according callbacks.

I'm calling bxSlider like this:

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            adaptiveHeight:false,
            infiniteLoop: false,
            onSlideNext: function ($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
                switch(newIndex){
                    case 0:
                    $(".pag2, .pag3, .pag4, .pag5, .pag6, .pag7, .pag8, .pag9, .pag10, .pag11, .pag12").hide(); 
                            $(".pag1").show();
                                break;

                                case 1:
                    $(".pag1, .pag3, .pag4, .pag5, .pag6, .pag7, .pag8, .pag9, .pag10, .pag11, .pag12").hide(); 
                                $(".pag2").show();
                                break;
                }           
            },
            onSlidePrev: function ($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
                switch(newIndex){
                    case 0:
                    $(".pag2, .pag3, .pag4, .pag5, .pag6, .pag7, .pag8, .pag9, .pag10, .pag11, .pag12").hide(); 
                            $(".pag1").show();
                                break;

                                case 1:
                    $(".pag1, .pag3, .pag4, .pag5, .pag6, .pag7, .pag8, .pag9, .pag10, .pag11, .pag12").hide(); 
                                $(".pag2").show();
                                break;
                      } 
            }
        });
```

The HTML Code is this:

```
<section class="pag1 section-height">
    <h2 class="slideTitle">Title</h2>
    <h3 class="slideText">"Text</h3>
</section>

 <section class="pag2 section-height">
    <h2 class="slideTitle">Title</h2>
    <h3 class="slideText">"Text</h3>
</section>
```

### Ask:

How can i get this to work? I need to link this slides in another page.

Comment: Without code, we cannot help.

Comment: Sorry, i edit the ask with the code i'm using.

Comment: but the current code you've shown is broken. was this a copy paste error?

Comment: What you mean with broken? I posted the parts of the code i'm using, This parts are refering where i have problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolve my problem using this:

```
if(window.location == 'mysite.com/#about') {
    slider.goToSlide(8); // Go to slide number 8 that is "About" slide.
}
```

So... on my pageb.html i have an link with `href="mysite.com/#about"` when page load bxSlider go to slide 8.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `data` attributes.
fox example:

`<ul class="bxslider">
        <li data-id="welcome">some content</li>
        <li data-id="about">some content</li>
        <li data-id="contact">some content</li>
    </ul>`

jQuery

`hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash) {
       startAt = $('.bxslider li[data-id="' + hash.replace('#', '') + '"]').index();
    }
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
       adaptiveHeight:false,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        startSlide: startAt?startAt:0
    });`

That all.

Hope this help